# Can IELTS Academic is acceptable for Quebec Skilled Worker Immigration Application?

Tags: immigration, canada, ielts, language-test

Does IELTS Academic is acceptable for QSW immigration ?
This link tells it but i am not sure yet .
http://www.canadim.com/new-qsw-list-2015/

Comment: Looking on the actual [Quebec immigration website](http://www.immigration-quebec.gouv.qc.ca/EN/immigrate-settle/permanent-workers/official-immigration-application/requirements-programs/language-knowledge.html), it doesn't state whether the IELTS Academic is valid or not. I'm not sure I would trust CANADIM because it states you don't need a financial guarantee but the [official website](http://www.immigration-quebec.gouv.qc.ca/EN/immigrate-settle/permanent-workers/official-immigration-application/requirements-programs/glossary.html#financial) says you do.

Comment: @mkennedy i contacted the Quebec Immigration Department and they said that both IELTS modules are acceptable.

Comment: That's great! Please make it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted the Quebec Immigration Department and they said that both IELTS modules are acceptable.